# Question mark in SAS

Tags: sas

What does the question mark in SAS mean?

```
proc print data=employees;
   where name ? W;
run;
```

I read [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000180357.htm) that it is used in the input statement to supress warnings. But in the above example it is in the `where`. I presume it means `contains`. What is the difference of using  `?` in input and `where`?

Comment: If I recall correctly it's the same as if your statement was `where name contains W`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this documentation article](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202951.htm), `?` is one of several `where`-only operators which only work in a `where` statement (largely a result of the `where` statement working more like a SQL query `where` than a natural SAS statement).

There is no relationship between this and the `?` usage in an input statement.